# Can't make Identity go to my database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Trying to make Identity work on my project and use my azure database, but when I change the "DefaultConnection" to the connection string I am using in my Database Context, I get this error.

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

**Source**

[image: Source]

Here is my Database Context

```
public partial class FitnessEntities : DbContext
{
    public FitnessEntities()
        : base("name=FitnessEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Exercis> Exercises { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MuscleGroup> MuscleGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
}
```

And here I changed the Default Connection to what I have in my Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("FitnessEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what code to include, if there is anything else needed, please ask me to include it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` in context which you use in code. Your database context should look like this

```
public partial class FitnessEntities : DbContext
{
    public FitnessEntities()
        : base("name=FitnessEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Exercis> Exercises { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MuscleGroup> MuscleGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Muscle> Muscles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```